# Can't create links to any Django admin templates beside index.html?

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to create a link to Django's admin/auth/user/add/ to let users create an account to login with. This is when I ran into the problem that even though setting

href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"

works for linking to the admin's index.html, replacing index with any other template's name doesn't work. So, I have no way of adding new accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse an admin URL you can follow the patterns [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

The URL name for the add page for a model is `{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_add`, the url you want is

```
{% url 'admin:auth_user_add' %}
```